# How to pass sightly variable as an argument to java script

Tags: javascript, aem, sightly

This is my code:

```
<div id="highcharts-sjlyUWsr">
<script src="https://app.everviz.com/inject/sjlyUWsr/" defer="defer" onerror="failed(${sightlyVariable})"></script>
</div>
```

Notice : I have passed sightly variable in javascript function which is throwing an error message and not working.

Comment: What error? and what you mean by "_not working_"? What is the current behaviour? What is the expected behaviour?

Comment: Is this `java` related in any way? Since the tag.

Comment: java script != javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
 <script src="https://app.everviz.com/inject/sjlyUWsr/"
 data-sly-test.err="failed('${sightlyVariable}')" defer="defer" onerror="${err@ context='attribute'}" 
></script>
```